# Isert new row in sql dosn't accept text

Tags: c#, database

I want to insert new row in my database from user input, i use C# and sql insert syntax. My problem is when i run a program all field compltely fill except text value (name of the product) which fill with another number (price) i check the syntax and the code but it's never work.

```
         public DataBaseManager (string DataBaseFilename)
{
    strFileName = DataBaseFilename;
    strFileNamenopath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName);
    strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(strFileName).Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), "") + "; Extended Properties=dBase III;Mode=ReadWrite";

    conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);

    conn.Open();
}

public void AddData(string Column, string value)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0; 
        char[] delimiterChars = { ','};


        queryCutting = @"INSERT INTO [" + strFileNamenopath  + "] ( " + Column +  " ) VALUES ( " + value + " )";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryCutting, conn);
        string[] _valseperated = value.Split(delimiterChars);
        string[] _columnsbase = Column.Split(delimiterChars);


        foreach (string str in _columnsbase )
        {              
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(str,SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  _valseperated[i];
            i++;

        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);        
    }

private void AddnewCode_Buttion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _productBase.AddData("code, pv1, achat, designat", "123456789" +  ", " + Textbox_Achat.Text + ", " + Textbox_Achat.Text +", " + Produitsnom_TextBox.Text);

        }
```

Value of column represent the column name in databse , value is the text box value.

```
Column = "code, pv1, achat, designat";
Value = "123456789, 10, 10, Productname";
```

value of queryCutting

```
queryCutting = "INSERT INTO [produits.dbf] ( code, pv1, achat, designat ) VALUES ( 123456789, 540, 120, NewProduct)"
```

[image]

Comment: You are passing two time the _Textbox_Achat.Text_ Is this your real code or just a typo?

Comment: Looks like Produitsnom_TextBox.Text is empty.   If you have a primary key and the key already exists in the table INSERT will not work and you need to use UPDATE. the instruction cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer and if the integer is zero (rows affected) equals zero then the database did not make any changes.

Comment: this is a real code, the probelm is product name is not insertinto row and the text is replaced with 'code' column value, and the Produitsnom_TextBox.Text is not empty

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger and look at what is the exact text of _queryCutting_ and if the parameters values follow exactly the order of the fields names. OleDb doesn't use the parameter's name to assign the values but only the order in which the parameters are added to the collection

Comment: Why are you adding parameters, when your query uses hard-coded sql-injection values from it's input, too? You should use parameters **instead** of string formatting your SQL command. Why are you doing this at all? Why format all your values into a text only to ave to parse them out of there two lines later?

Comment: When you have the exact text of _queryCutting_, execute that directly in your database and note any errors. Pay attention to quotes around text values

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i try to excute the 'queryCutting' but the same!!

Comment: What string delimiter does your database use? Whatever it is, you must use it. BTW, first time I heard "query cutting"

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood your problem. You set the *Value* string directly in the query text so you should get this result

```
   "INSERT INTO [theFolderName] (code, pv1, achat, designat) 
    VALUES ( 123456789, 10, 10, Productname )";
```

The first three values are accepted as correct values for the numeric fields and no parameter is taken in consideration for these fields, but when the parser reaches the *ProductName* "value" it cannot use as a value because it is not a inside quotes. So it thinks it is a parameter and searches the Parameters collection. Because in OleDb parameters are positional, it takes the first parameter and passes its value to the OleDbCommand. And the first parameter is the Code.

This should solve the problem. Don't give a parameter name (OleDb doesn't care) and let the OleDbCommand use the complete set of parameters given in the exact order expected

```
public void AddData(string Column, string value)
{
    try
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ','};

        // Query text is incomplete, we complete it inside the loop
        queryCutting = @"INSERT INTO [" + strFileNamenopath  + @"] 
                         ( " + Column +  " ) VALUES ( ";

        // The query and the connection will be set after the loop
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        string[] _valseperated = value.Split(delimiterChars);
        string[] _columnsbase = Column.Split(delimiterChars);

        foreach (string str in _columnsbase )
        {              
            // The second parameter in AddWithValue is the Value not the type.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(str, _valseperated[i]);

            // Add a placeholder for each parameter
            queryCutting += "?,";
        }

        // Remove the ending colon an close the paren on the query text
        queryCutting = queryCutting.Substring(queryCutting.Length-1) + ")";
        cmd.CommandText = queryCutting;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);        
    }
}
```

Notice that this code doesn't solve your Sql Injection problem. You should be absolutely sure that your user doesn't type itself neither the file name/folder neither the name of the columns and choose these values from a whitelisted set of values

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by add insering Produitsnom_TextBox.Text betwwen qutes like this

```
_productBase.AddData("code, designat ,pv1, achat", "123456789" + ", " + "' " +Produitsnom_TextBox.Text + "'"  + ", " + Vente_TextBox.Text + ", " + Textbox_Achat.Text );
```

also i removed the parametes part.

```
public void AddData(string Column, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = -1;
            char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };


            queryCutting = @"INSERT INTO [" + strFileNamenopath + "] ( " + Column + " ) VALUES ( " + value + " )";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryCutting, conn);


            MessageBox.Show(queryCutting);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);        
        }


    }
```